# HTML validator for Win32?

Tags: html, validation, w3c

Does anybody know a fast, free local HTML validator to copy-and-paste code in, that shows errors directly on their respective lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out [HTMLTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)

If you like to work from within the browser , [HTML VALIDATOR](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/) and [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60)

Answer (score 7):

you can [download the w3c](http://validator.w3.org/source/) validator and [install it](http://validator.w3.org/docs/install_win.html)

Answer (score 5):

Firefox has an excellent set of plugins for web development- [Html validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249) is the one you're looking for.